# Singular of "vertices"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, pronunciation, latin, irregular

I often hear the word *vertice* (pronounced VER-tee-cee) used as the singular of *vertices* instead of *vertex*.

- Is *vertice* an acceptable singular for *vertices*? If so, how is it pronounced?
- On the other hand, is *vertexes* an acceptable plural for *vertex*?

Comment: No and sadly yes - but then I had many years of Latin, but few of English. Vertice is a sparkling white vine.

Comment: +1 for calling out one of my pet peeves. I used to get hit with it a lot when I taught geometry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The singular is **vertex**.

According to the [Merriam-Webster dictionary entry for vertex](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vertex), both *vertices* and *vertexes* can be used as the plural of *vertex*. *Vertice* is not listed as a word.

> **ver·tex**
>
> noun \ˈvər-ˌteks\
>
> plural ver·ti·ces\ˈvər-tə-ˌsēz\ also
>   ver·tex·es

The same happens with *[index](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/index)*, for example, where the plural can be both *indices* and *indexes*.

According to the same dictionary, *vertex* and *index* both originated from Latin:

**Vertex**

> Middle English, top of the head, from
>   Latin vertic-, vertex, vortic-, vortex
>   whirl, whirlpool, top of the head,
>   summit, from vertere to turn

**Index**

> Latin indic-, index, from indicare to
>   indicate First Known Use: 1561

---

Explanation for the two forms of plural from [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-ind2.htm):

> Index is one of those rare oddball
>   words with two different plurals in
>   English. English copied the original
>   Latin plural at first, making indices.
>   As with a lot of other Latin plurals,
>   the standard English way of marking
>   the plural, using -s or -es, has
>   progressively been taking over, making
>   indexes.

(..)

> Other words retain their Latin
>   plurals, but we have to work at
>   remembering them because the English
>   plural marker has otherwise so few
>   exceptions: apices (of apex), corpora
>   (of corpus), helices (of helix),
>   matrices (of matrix), **vertices** (of
>   vertex) and many others.

Notice that based on the last paragraph above, the author of the article does not consider *vertexes* a valid plural of *vertex*.

Additionally, *vertices* is much more used  than *vertexes*: [12.600.000 occurrences of *vertices* vs. 26.700 occurrences of *vertexes* in Google](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=vertices&word2=vertexes). My Firefox's spell checker disagrees though. It doesn't know *vertices* but it does know *vertexes*.

As for *vertex* vs. *vertice*, there are [2.680.000 occurrences of vertex in Google and 130.000 occurrences of *vertice*](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=vertice&word2=vertex).

These numbers also lead to a possible explanation for why people sometimes say *vertice*. The plural form *vertices* is more than 4 times more used than the correct singular form *vertex*. So it's possible that people derive *vertice* from *vertices* because they hear the plural form *vertices* much more often than the singular form *vertex*.

Comment: If you're in a subversive, Germanic mood, you might go with "vertexen" and "indexen" instead, with 4K and 803K results, respectively, the former largely in countries that speak Germanic languages, and the latter occuring mainly due to the pairing of a Web site's "index" with the ISO 639-1 "en" language code, which unfortunately obscures the results.

Comment: Note that "vértice" is vertex in Spanish, so a query for "vertice" might include results in Spanish as well.

Comment: To this day, I still cringe when somebody uses the plural form "vertexes". It seems to be not uncommon in computer graphics circles, see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6UKhR0T6cs

Answer (score 3):

Neither Merriam-Webster nor Wiktionary have an entry for *vertice*, and I have never encountered it myself. Then again, I am heavily biased, working a lot with [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).

The [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) has 44 cites for *vertex*, 19 for *vertices*, but none for *vertice* (well, it does have exactly one, but [judge for yourself](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=vertice&mysubmit=Go)).

All that being said, I think it is only natural for someone who encounters the plural form *vertices* for the first time in his life to derive the singular form as *vertice*. Looking at your location and [its demographics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando,_Florida#Demographics), I think that Spanish influence could be yet another factor in your immediate environment, the Spanish word for *vertex* being *vértice*.

As to the plural form, *vertices* is much more common, but *vertexes* is not incorrect, see e.g. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vertex) or [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertex). The BNC has 5 cites for *vertexes* (but again, 19 for *vertices*).

Answer (score 2):

1. The singular of vertices is only vertex, although in colloquial language it may have developed into "vertice" as well, though this is not technically correct.
2. To answer your second question, vertexes is not technically correct, but again is used often in modern-day language and as a result has become an accepted term. However, to be completely correct, I would use vertices, and likewise vertex and NOT vertice for the singular form of this word.